# Meteor Initiate with Remote MongoDB on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Working on a project where I need to connect my meteor project to a remote MongoDB server from windows. Where do I set the environment variable(MONGO_URL="DB LINK") on windows?

I have already done it from OSX from the terminal setting the environment variable MONGO_URL="Mongo DB Link" meteor. But can't seem to do it on windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple search of [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt) ( another stackexchange site ) where you should have asked the question. Or just looked through search results.

Comment: Thanks man!! This link was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Open a Commandline Interface in Windows and type following command

```
C:\ SET MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@host:port/dbname
```

This works for me